# Session not working on Joomla Module?

Tags: session, joomla, module

How can we use a session at created in a normal PHP file in Joomla modules?

I created normal PHP file and created session in PHP file `$_SESSION['string']`.

Also I have created Joomla module. I want to use the session value created in a normal PHP file on Joomla module, but when I try to get the session value in module like this:

```
$string = JFactory::getSession();
$string->get('string');

print var_dump($string);
```

It returns null value.

What can I do fix this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You need to explain what you are asking, what research you have done, what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: Can you help me Elin now :)

Comment: when you say you created a normal PHP file, do you mean a proper module or simply a normal PHP that you have just upload to your website?

Comment: Normal PHP file that uploaded

Comment: getSession() is going to get the session for the current user. In this case you do not have a current user.  YOu need to getSesssion for some specific user.  YOU can't just throw joomla classes into a external file, you need to bootstrap the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In your normal php file

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$string = JFactory::getSession();
$string->set('string','your_session_value'); // instead of $_SESSION[]
```

Also in your module

```
$string = JFactory::getSession();
echo $string->get('string');
```

If you are trying to access normal session values inside joomla framework it will not work.
Also if you need to use joomla session out side framework you have to load the framework on that page.

Hope this may helps you..

Comment: Thank you jobin.But this not enough.I have a image.php file for captcha that using module page.image.php:

Comment: Thank you jobin.But this not enough.I have a image.php file for captcha that using module page.image.php,Every page renew creating a new captcha and saving in session.Your code getting the only first captcha .

Comment: The captcha creating page and checking page you need to include joomla framework. Then it will work. Bcoz when ever the captcha loaded that time you have to assign it to joomla session.

Comment: I have same situation while ago i fixed it like this way :)